Is there a way we can use same navController in two different navHost in android jetpack for type safe navigation
I am using a bottom navigation in android jetpack
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar() {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    var navigationSelectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), bottomBar = {
        NavigationBar {
            BottomNavigationItem().bottomNavigationItems()
                .forEachIndexed { index, bottomNavigationItem ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        selected = index == navigationSelectedItem,
                        label = {
                            Text(text = bottomNavigationItem.label, fontSize = bottomNavTextSize)
                        },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painterResource(id = bottomNavigationItem.icon),
                                contentDescription = bottomNavigationItem.label,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(iconSize),
                                tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.White else Color.Black
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            navigationSelectedItem = index
                          navController.navigate(bottomNavigationItem.navigationDestination::class.java.name) {
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
        }
    }) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationDestination.HomeScreen,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            composable<NavigationDestination.HomeScreen> {
                HomeScreen(navController)
            }
            composable<NavigationDestination.StatisticsScreen> {
                StatisticsScreen(navController)
            }
            composable<NavigationDestination.ProfileScreen> {
                ProfileScreen(navController)
            }
            composable<NavigationDestination.TrackingScreen> {
                TrackingScreen() // Your tracking screen implementation
            }
        }
    }
}

on home screen I am navigating to tracking screen

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(TopPaddingExtraLarge)
        )

        StartTrackButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(NavigationDestination.TrackingScreen) {
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
            },
            text = "START"
        )
    }
}


Also I am using a pending intent using and want to open the same instance of tracking screen on click of notification that I have handled

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val navigationDestination = mutableStateOf<NavigationDestination?>(null)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen().apply {

        }

        navigateToTrackingScreen(intent)

        setContent {
            WalkTrackerTheme(dynamicColor = false) {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                LaunchedEffect(navigationDestination.value) {
                    navigationDestination.value?.let {
                        navController.navigate(it) {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                        navigationDestination.value = null
                    }
                }

                NavHost(navController, startDestination = NavigationDestination.RunTrackerScreen) {
                    composable<NavigationDestination.Onboarding> {
                        OnBoardingScreen(navController)
                    }
                    composable<NavigationDestination.InputDetailScreen> {
                        InputDetailScreen()
                    }
                    composable<NavigationDestination.RunTrackerScreen> {
                        RunScreen(navController)
                    }
                    composable<NavigationDestination.TrackingScreen> {
                        TrackingScreen()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        navigateToTrackingScreen(intent)
    }

    private fun navigateToTrackingScreen(intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == ACTION_SHOW_TRACKING_SCREEN) {
            navigationDestination.value = NavigationDestination.TrackingScreen
        }
    }
}


When I start the service from the tracking screen I got a notification and When I tried to open the tracking screen on click of a notification using a pending intent. I opened a whole new instance of Tracking screen.
How can I resolve this.
